# Need help creating a pentagon network

Tags: graphics, geometry

I'm trying to fit 5 pentagons around a pentagon, but it's not right. Please help.

[image: my attempt]

```
p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}]
Graphics[{Line[p],
  Table[Rotate[
    Translate[Line[p],
     1.5 {Cos[t - 18], Sin[t - 18]}],
    t/2],
   {t, 72 Degree Range[5]}]}]
```

Comment: This needs more detail to be understandable.

Comment: What you want is the first step of generating the ["pentaflake" fractal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pentaflake.html). That page goes in detail on how the pentagons fit together.

Comment: Thank you for the reference @J.M. Did you get a notice from my comment on question 84939?

Comment: Did you not check your inbox for responses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be what you seek:

```
Graphics[{
    FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.5]], EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}],
    RegularPolygon[5],
    FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.8]],
    RegularPolygon[#, {1, 3 Pi/10}, 5] & /@ CirclePoints[{2 Cos[Pi/5], 3 Pi/10}, 5],
  }
]
```

[image: a crown of polygons]

All pentagons have radius 1, for convenience. The central pentagon is centered on the origin, so the outer pentagons have centers at a distance equal to twice the apothem of the central pentagon, and at positions equally spaced around a circle which can be obtained from `CirclePoints` using an appropriate angular shift.

Looking at the figure, I noticed that the outer pentagons all have the same angular with respect to the horizontal axis, which simplifies matters considerably, so they are constructed using `RegularPolygon` using the center locations obtained from `CirclePoints` above, and with a constant radius and angular position with respect to the $x$ axis.

Comment: Just learned what an apothem is. `2 Cos[π/5]`. Thanks. It looks like you are using the form of `RegularPolygon[{x, y}, {r, θ}, n]` but your `θ` is static. Where does the rotation come from?

Comment: When you generate 5 of them with different `{x,y}`, do they all just orient themselves with respect to `{0,0}`?

Comment: @shirha There is no need for rotation of the external pentagons. They are all oriented in the same way. That is what I was referring to in the answer that simplified matters considerably. Given their five-fold symmetry, the five-fold rotation around the origin would make each original and rotate one indistinguishable, so in practice no need to rotate.

Comment: Wow. I see it now! It's like an optical illusion. Thank you @MarcoB for such a great solution. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course, `2 Cos[π/5]` is just the same as `GoldenRatio`.

Answer (score 2):

```
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Net"] /. Polygon[x_] :> Polygon[Take[x, 6]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do Nets have Faces and/or Vertices?