# Need help understanding Graphics Translate

Tags: graphics, geometry, geometric-transform

I created a star pattern that I was trying to apply to a circle of pentagons, but the `Translate` had a slight offset, and I don't understand why. When I drew the lines, they were relative to the origin, but when I used the same `CirclePoints` I used for the pentagons, the star pattern didn't follow. So I tried a pentagon wrapper, and it also had a different offset. Finally, the circle wrapper solved it. What am I missing here?

If you have another solution for the star, I would like to see that, but I would like the inner lines to trisect each other. Also, I would like to get this working in `Graphics3D`, but that's for a different post.

.

[image]

```
p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}];
mid[p1_, p2_] := p1 + (p2 - p1) .42;
m = mid[p[[#[[1]]]], p[[#[[2]]]]] & /@ {
   {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {5,1}, {1, 5}};

(* star only *)
star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}} 

(* star + Polygon[5] *)
star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}, 
       EdgeForm[{Thin,Black}],FaceForm[],RegularPolygon[5]}

(* star + Circle[] *)
star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}, Thin, Circle[]}

color = {"Purple", "Green", "Magenta", "Cyan", "Red"}
cp = CirclePoints[{2 Cos[π/5], 3 π/10}, 5];
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Yellow, RegularPolygon[5],
  CapForm["Round"], Thick, Black, star, {
     Lighter[RGBColor[color[[#]]]],
     RegularPolygon[cp[[#]], {1, 3 π/10}, 5],
     Black, Rotate[Translate[star, cp[[#]]], 6 π/10]
     } & /@ Range[5]
  }]
```

Comment: Add code for the first two images that have a problem?

Comment: star only 
`star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}}` 
star + Pentagon 
`star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}, EdgeForm[{Thin,Black}],FaceForm[],RegularPolygon[5]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can combine the results of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220773) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220934) to obtain the desired picture.

First, we find the value of `u` (in the notation of the second answer) such that the lines within the polygons are mutually trisecting. As a warm-up geometric exercise, I invite you to figure out why the following snippet gives the correct answer:

```
sides = Partition[CirclePoints[5], 2, 1, 1];
u = ut /. RootReduce[First[Solve[Equal @@
    MapThread[Dot, {{{1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 1/3}}, 
                    Transpose[{{1 - ut, ut}.# & /@ Take[sides, 2],
                               {ut, 1 - ut}.# & /@ Take[sides, {3, 4}]}]}], ut]]]
   (15 - Sqrt[5])/22
```

Then, generate the required lines:

```
net = Line[RootReduce[Transpose[{{1 - u, u}.# & /@ sides,
                                 RotateLeft[{u, 1 - u}.# & /@ sides, 2]}]]];
```

From there, we can apply the results of the first answer:

```
With[{cc = CirclePoints[{GoldenRatio, 3 π/10}, 5]},
     Graphics[{{Yellow, RegularPolygon[5]},
               MapThread[{Lighter[#2], RegularPolygon[#, {1, 3 π/10}, 5]} &,
                         {cc, {Purple, Green, Magenta, Cyan, Red}}],
               {net, Map[Composition[TranslationTransform[#],
                                     RotationTransform[π]], net, {2}] & /@ cc}},
              BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Directive[Black, Thick], 
                                     EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thick]]]]]
```

[image: figure]

---

A slight modification of the code above can be used to get a 3D embedding. (As another exercise, spot the differences between the previous code and the following one.)

```
With[{cc = PadRight[CirclePoints[{GoldenRatio, 3 π/10}, 5], {Automatic, 3}]},
     Graphics3D[{{Yellow, Polygon[PadRight[CirclePoints[5], {Automatic, 3}]]},
                 MapThread[{Lighter[#2], 
                            Polygon[PadRight[CirclePoints[Take[#, 2], {1, 3 π/10}, 5],
                                             {Automatic, 3}]]} &,
                           {cc, {Purple, Green, Magenta, Cyan, Red}}],
                 {Map[PadRight[#, {Automatic, 3}] &, net, {2}], 
                  Map[Composition[TranslationTransform[#],
                                  RotationTransform[π, {0, 0, 1}], 
                      PadRight[#, {Automatic, 3}] &], net, {2}] & /@ cc}
                  /. Line -> Tube},
                BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Black,
                                       EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thick]]],
                Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: 3D diagram]

Comment: There a lot I still don't understand yet like all the Thread functions. I don't know how to use ReplaceAll and the last time i heard of a dot product was in high school when Kennedy was President. I find your code fascinating but it will take me time to understand it and apply it to my project. Until then, thank you for your replay. I value it very much.

Comment: I encourage you to take your time studying it. I would definitely encourage you to read up on dot products if you're going to be doing a lot of geometric stuff; they tend to show up a lot in the required computations, and it is vastly useful to know how to manipulate them.