# Crop a Pentagram with a Pentagon

Tags: graphics, geometry

Is it possible to crop a Pentagram to a Pentagon region? I would like to remove the tips in figure 1 so it looks like figure 2.

.

Figure 1.
[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[], RegularPolygon[5], Black,
  Line@Table[{Cos[k 2π/5 + 3π/10], Sin[k 2π/5 + 3π/10]}, {k, 0, 4*2*5, 2}]}]
```

Figure 2.
[image]

```
p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}];
mid[p1_, p2_] := p1 + (p2 - p1) .42;
m = mid[p[[#[[1]]]], p[[#[[2]]]]] & /@ {
   {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {5,1}, {1, 5}};
star = {Line[m[[#]]] & /@ {{2, 5}, {4, 7}, {8, 1}, {6, 9}, {10, 3}}}

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[], RegularPolygon[5], star}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rp = RegularPolygon[5];

pentagram = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ Polygon @ 
    CirclePoints[{1, 3 Pi/10}, 5][[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]];

Graphics[{MeshPrimitives[RegionIntersection[rp, pentagram], 1], RegionBoundary[rp]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I find this extremely interesting! Do you have any suggestions on how I may learn more about Meshes and GraphicsComplexes?

Comment: @shirha, you may find the following tutorials useful: [tutorial - Efficient Representation of Many Primitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EfficientRepresentationOfManyPrimitives.html) , [FEM - ElementMesh Creation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) and [FEM - ElementMesh Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
pentagram = N@Table[{Cos[k 2 \[Pi]/5 + 3 \[Pi]/10], Sin[k 2 \[Pi]/5 + 3 \[Pi]/10]}, {k, 0, 4*2*5, 2}];
lines = RegionIntersection[RegularPolygon[5], Line[pentagram]];

Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}],
  FaceForm[],
  RegularPolygon[5],
  lines
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `N@` necessary to prevent an infinite loop?

Comment: @shirha What makes you think it's an infinite loop? It's not. It just takes that much longer to find the symbolic expressions for the line segments. It's much easier to find them numerically.

Answer (score 2):

The region-based solutions are nice, but do more work than necessary. Allow me to present a method based on linear interpolation with some clever shuffling:

```
Manipulate[With[{sides = Partition[CirclePoints[5], 2, 1, 1]},
                Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], RegularPolygon[5]}, 
                          Line /@ Transpose[{{1 - u, u}.# & /@ sides, 
                                             RotateLeft[{u, 1 - u}.# & /@ sides, 2]}]}]],
           {{u, (3 - GoldenRatio)/5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Manipulate object]

Values of `u` that are greater than $1/2$ will generate your cropped pentagram, e.g.

[image: Manipulate object]

Comment: Is there an easy way to find all the intersection points when u = .6? I can't figure out how to apply `Solve` to all the correct pairs of lines without picking them by hand.

Comment: That's worth asking as a separate question.