# My first Mathematica project code review, Dodecahedron

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, code-review, polyhedra

I thought of a project to get my feet wet with Mathematica and have completed it. If anyone finds time to look at the code and send some feedback I would appreciate it. If it's inappropriate to ask and you close this question, I will understand. It's important to me to learn how to write idiomatic code. This has been fun and I have already received lots of helpful suggestions here on SE. Here's a screen shot and a link to the notebook on dropbox.

[image: megaminx]

[megademo.nb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdo0uuobqgwsx53/megademo.nb)

Comment: I'm not really qualified to critique, but I think everything looks fairly idiomatic to me, and the code is fairly readable. Otherwise, I think it's a really neat project! It's like a Rubik's dodecahedron. I think finding a project that you think is neat is a great way to learn a language, and this exploits some of the graphics and dynamic features that might be much more difficult in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not able to evaluate the OP's notebook, as it uses stuff that can't be parsed by version 11.2. Nevertheless, let me show a small demonstration of coloring a dodecahedron and adding lines to it, using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220936), and the built-in `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]`:

```
Graphics3D[{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[4]]], 
            Transpose[{RandomSample[Lighter /@ {Yellow, Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Gray,
                                                Magenta, Brown, Orange, Pink,
                                                Purple, White}], 
                       First[Normal[N @ PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron",
                                                       "GraphicsComplex"]]] /. 
                       Polygon[p_] :> 
                       With[{sides = Partition[p, 2, 1, 1], ut = (15 - Sqrt[5])/22},
                            {Polygon[p],
                             {Black, Line[Transpose[{{1 - ut, ut}.# & /@ sides, 
                                                     RotateLeft[{ut, 1 - ut}.# & /@
                                                                sides, 2]}]]
                            }}]}]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: colored dodecahedron]

You might be able to modify it for your actual demonstration.

Comment: It works in the 12.1 Player. Do you know what I used to break 11.2? I would like my demo to work there also. I definitely want to study this. I thought there was a way to do this using the polyhedronData. Thanks again for another great answer!

Comment: I don't doubt that it works in the current version. Nevertheless, I am providing an alternative that might still be useful, even in older versions.

Comment: @shirha My guess would be `Polygon`. It received some updates in V12, so you might be calling it in a way that earlier versions don't understand.